# What is the difference between render size and display size

Tags: html, html5-canvas, styles, height, width

What is the difference between render size (width and height) and display size (style.width and style.height)

Even when I change it to px it is still not same.

These are the examples 
https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/oWLZaR

```
<canvas id="chart_0" height="40vw" width="80vw"></canvas>
```

https://codepen.io/chartjs/pen/WjxpmO

```
<canvas id="chart_0" style="height:40vh; width:80vw">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [style width vs width attribute in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373726/style-width-vs-width-attribute-in-html)

Comment: `canvas.width` & `canvas.height` set resolution and is always in pixels and should not be post fixed with a CSS unit type eg good `width="300"`. bad `width="300vw"` Resolution is the number of pixels that an image contains. `canvas.style.width` & `canvas.style.height` sets the display size (amount of space the canvas occupies  on the page) and is independent of canvas resolution. Display size must be in any of the valid CSS units.

Answer (score 0):

`height=""` and `width=""` are HTML and do not use "view height" or "view width", only fixed sizes.

`vh` and `vw` are used in CSS only.