# HTML inline style vs style attributes (which is better)

Tags: html, attributes, inline-styles

I have encountered a simple question but can't find the answer. The question is that, when I want to use inline style, for example width and height for an element in HTML, is it better to do it by width attribute or by inline style width?

```
<div style="width:${widthx}; height:${heightx};"></div>
```

VS.

```
<div width="${widthx}" height="${heightx}"></div>
```

what about one of them being deprecated or better for SEO solutions?

Comment: possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373726/style-width-vs-width-attribute-in-html

Comment: Nope. Not completely duplicate. This is more general and more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this MDN link for [HTML Attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes), you should use `style` as attributes for `<div>` (or elements that are not `<canvas>, <embed>, <iframe>, <img>, <input>, <object>, <video>`) are considered legacy.

From the linked MDN article:

> Note: For all other instances, such as `<div>`, this is a legacy attribute, in which case the CSS width property should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

The size is about styling so you should use CSS for it, however you need to add px to define the unit of the height and width.

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes) says regarding the height attribute:

> Note: In some instances, such as `<div>`, this is a legacy attribute, in which case the CSS height property should be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Along with what others have hinted at. Using style is more appropriate, as the width attribute only exists on specific elements.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_width.asp